# Como hago para que una consulta mysql que me cuenta los registros cuando encuentro un valor nulo o vacio me ponga cero

Tags: mysql

Me pueden ayudar por favor, estoy realizando una cuenta de registros de devolucion de tramites, pero tengo un problema que la consulta cuando hay un motivo de devolucion que no tiene registros no me lo muestra en los resultados, necesito que si no hay motivos registrados me ponga el valor cero.

He intentado con las siguientes consultas, pero todas me dan el mismo resultado.

```html
SELECT motivo, sede, COUNT(case when motivo IS NULL then 1 else 0 end) AS total FROM invtramites WHERE sede = 'VIVA' and exitoso = 'NO' GROUP BY motivo;
SELECT motivo, sede, IFNULL(count(*), 0) AS total FROM invtramites where sede = 'VIVA' and exitoso = 'NO' GROUP BY motivo;
SELECT motivo, sede, COALESCE(count(motivo), 0) AS total FROM invtramites WHERE sede = 'VIVA' and exitoso = 'NO' GROUP BY motivo;
```

El resultado que obtengo con cualquiera de las 3 es el mismo:

[image: resultados]

como dije, necesito que si la consulta encuentra un motivo de devolucion sin ningun registro me lo muestre en la lista con total cero.

TENGO 2 TABLAS, INVTRAMITES y MOTIVOS. en motivos estan los tipo de devolucion en el campo motivo_devolucion y necesito contar en invtramites cuantas de esas devoluciones hay y si alguna devolucion no se ha realizado que me la muestre con total = 0.

Me pueden ayudar muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola. La pregunta no es clara. Explica qué quieres decir con esto: *necesito que si la consulta encuentra un motivo de devolucion sin ningun registro me lo muestre en la lista con total cero*  y muestra un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable de tus datos.

Comment: Hola, si mira, yo tengo una tabla donde los usuarios me registran los motivos de devolución de un tramite, esos motivos yo ya los tengo pre definidos en la pagina web, ellos deben seleccionarlo y guardar.  el problema es que cuando voy a realizar el reporte del total de devoluciones por motivos.. si tengo algun motivo sin registros no me lo muestra y necesito que me salga cero en la tabla.

Comment: Donde esta la tabla motivos, porque pienso que podrias con un left join mostrar, pero siento que falta mas datos para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Necesitas partir de una tabla maestra con los tipos de tramites ¿la tienes? ¿podrías indicarnos como se llama?

Comment: hola, la tabla que contiene las devoluciones se llama, motivos y el campo motivo_devolucion

Answer (score 0):

Debes incluir los registros para que muestre Null y luego ese Null transformarlo en 0, para incluir los registros debes modificar el "Where" para que tambien incluya los null.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Cordial saludo,

Encontre la solucion con esto:

```html
select invtramites.motivo, IFNULL(count(motivos.motivo_devolucion), 0) AS total from invtramites LEFT JOIN motivos ON invtramites.motivo = motivos.motivo_devolucion AND sede = 'VIVA' and exitoso = 'NO' WHERE motivo != '' GROUP BY invtramites.motivo;
```

Donde ya el resultado me dio esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias